# C# Deserialize Array as root element

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have an XML document I need to deserialize where the root element is an array of items, such as

```
<Items>
  <Item></Item>
  <Item></Item>
</Items>
```

I have tried creating a class that inherits from a collection such as like...

```
public class Items : IEnumerable<Item>
```

but I have not been able to get it to work. I get an error that says, `<items>` is not expected. I am not even sure it is possible to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following declaration of the `Items` class works as you need:

```
[XmlRoot("Items")]
public class Items : List<Item>
{
}
```

The `XmlRootAttribute` does the trick, letting the `XmlSerializer` know about the root element. It then expects elements for items named according to the the `Item` class.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.